# Saving more than one value to a Dictionary key in a loop with an Array

Tags: swift, dictionary, parse-platform

I have this block of code

```
//start of the loop
if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
    for object in objects {
        //saving the object
        self.likerNames.setObject(object["fromUserName"]!, forKey: saveStatusId!)
   }
}
```

*likerNames* is an NSMutableArray declared earlier, *saveStatusId* is a string I also declared and saved earlier (It's just an objectId as a String), and *object["fromUserName"]* is an object returned from my query (not shown above).

Everything is working fine as it is but my query sometimes returns more than one *object["fromUserName"]* to the same key which is *saveStatusId.* When this happens the value I have for that *saveStatusId* is replaced when I actually want it to be added to the key.

So want it to kind of look like this

```
("jKd98jDF" : {"Joe", "John"})
("ksd6fsFs" : {"Sarah"})
("payqw324" : {"Chris", "Sarah", "John"})
```

I know you can use Arrays but I'm not sure how I would go about that to get it to work in my current situation.

So my question would be how to I get my key (*saveStatusId*) to store more than one value of *object["fromUserName"]*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
let key = saveStatusId!
let oldValue = self.likerNames.objectForKey( key ) as? [String]
let newValue = (oldValue ?? []) + [ object["fromUserName" ] ]
self.likerNames.setObject( newValue, forKey: key )
```

If likerNames has an array in slot[saveStatusId], append the new value, otherwise create an array and put that in the right slot

Comment: This seems like it would work but I get an error in the third line (newValue) saying "AnyObject is not convertible to String." And when I try to downcast it to a String it tells me "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '(String)' and '[AnyObject?]'"

Comment: object["fromUserName"] as! String

Comment: I should have mentioned, the errors on "(oldValue ?? [])"